# Does Russia/USSR have a S.H.I.E.L.D. equivalent?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, it's revealed that in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU), there was an Operation Paperclip at the end of World War II, just as [in real life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_paperclip).  In the MCU, the Soviet Union counterpart to Paperclip created the Winter Soldier, so the real world projects ended up having super-science ramifications in the MCU.  On the American side of this, we see the SSR (and later S.H.I.E.L.D.) absorb these scientists and their super-science accomplishments, but what about the Soviet Union?

Did the Soviet Union (and the countries it later split into) have a S.H.I.E.L.D. equivalent?  What did they accomplish, besides the Winter Soldier?

Comment: And yes, if we don't know yet, then I can wait until *Agent Carter*, which will take place in the right timeframe to shed light on this.

Comment: As I note in my answer below - the question doesn't make sense as written.  SHIELD is a global international agency which includes Russian and ex-KBG agents in its ranks.  Even the SSR isnt government specific - it's like a cross between NATO and the OSS.

The question shouldn't be "Does Russia have a SHIELD", it should be "Did the Axis have an SSR equivalent?"

Comment: @joshbirk The issue is that in canon, there was an Operation Paperclip.  So the Americans were trying to grab scientists and keep them out of Russian hands.  So the Russians must have been up to *something*.  We see them grab the Winter Soldier, so *someone* ran the Winter Soldier program in the USSR.  Per the history described in *Cap 2*, the SSR (which clearly didn't include the USSR) turned into SHIELD shortly after WWII.  The people running Winter Soldier didn't get blended with SHIELD until HYDRA infiltrated SHIELD.  What were they up to before that?

Comment: @joshbirk You yourself argue that there were non-SHIELD organizations here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54310/1027  So who are they?  What did they accomplish?  We know the Russians had something going, that's what this question asks about.

Comment: In that I am arguing that it is effectively Hydra and the KGB.  Perhaps you are trying to ask if Hydra has a precursor like SHIELD does?  It does not, Hydra predates both the USSR and Nazi Germany.  Specifically Russia gets more confusing, because WWII intelligence agencies were pretty immature concepts since they are pre Cold War, hence the reason the OSS is often exaggerated or entities like the SSR are fictionalized.  Again, it think you are asking if the USSR or the Axis had an SSR equivalent in the end.

Comment: Or I'm sorry - do you mean "Did the Russians have an Operation Paperclip"?  IE a specific intelligence/anti-intelligence program intended to poach Allied assets? (a la Bucky)?

Comment: @joshbirk Great, so your answer is that the USSR had the KGB, with some infiltration from HYDRA.  Now what did they accomplish?  We see the Winter Soldier getting frozen, he's got a mechanical arm.  Did they whip up any other advanced tech?

Comment: `so someone ran the Winter Soldier program in the USSR` - Yeah, and I recall we learned who during/near the end of TWS...

Comment: There is no real indication that the Russians/Axis had any super-tech program of their own (at least around WWII).  The cybernetics, cyro-freezing, etc., appears to all be of Hydra handiwork.

Answer (score 7):

**Technically, SHIELD is USSR's version of SHIELD**

Not to sound too snarky, but *SHIELD* is intended to be a global international organization - not one tied to a single nation.  That is why Fury has to answer to a World Security Council.  One could argue that SHIELD's priorities aren't properly global - but the goal isn't to be nation centric.  But note that Black Widow is ex-KGB and there are certainly ex-CIA members in the ranks of SHIELD as well.

Comment: Sorry, why the downvote?  It's technically correct.

Comment: Because 1, SHIELD didn't exist at the end of WWII, and 2, there's no mention of what the Soviet SSR-equivalent accomplished.

Comment: Then I would recommend rephrasing your question, as you are asking if USSR had an SSR equivalent - not if it has a SHIELD equivalent.  Very different things.